# how to scan test source code with the SonarQube Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to make a Jenkins job that only scans the test source files, so everything under `/src/test/java` (using Maven). I use the **SonarQube Jenkins** post-action for this.

When we used to configure Sonar in the pom file directly we could do this in a profile:

```
<sonar.sources>/src/test/java</sonar.sources>
<sonar.tests/>
```

That worked fine.

But in the Jenkins job I have to specify these as 'Additional properties' and I can't seem to specify an emtpy sonar.tests element. I tried `-Dsonar.tests`, `-Dsonar.tests=`,`-Dsonar.tests=""`, nothing works. When this element is not empty Sonar will attempt to scan the test files twice and crash.

Comment: You want to scan your tests - and only your tests - as though they were normal source code?

Comment: yes indeed, that's what I want to achieve, and already did before using the SonarQube Jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post-build step is specifically and explicitly a Maven operation. Your problem comes from trying to use Maven to do something un-Mavenish; i.e. ignore the convention that files in the tests directory should be treated as tests.

Since you want to scan your tests *as code*, your best bet is to use the build step (which uses [SonarQube Scanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)) and set your scanner properties manually. That will make it easy to set your sources directory and to *omit* the tests directory.

Comment: I'd say my problem comes from the fact that Sonar doesn't consider tests as code :) So there is no way to make the Jenkins plugin parse an empty sonar.tests property?

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts I guess you're applying 'normal' rules to tests?

Comment: Yes indeed (well not me, one of our developers, I maintain our Sonar and Jenkins)

Comment: But for instance we also have a test team that writes Selenium tests, they only have src/test/java since surefire/failsafe etc expect the code to be there and there is no business logic. But they also want to use Sonar to check for common rules, since they are not used to programming Java. Same problem there

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration @NicolasMommaerts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95556/discussion-between-nicolas-mommaerts-and-g-ann-sonarsource-team).